# Python pandas nasty delimiter issue

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to read a bunch of raw email text files into a pandas dataframe (Python 3.5) so I can feed it to a classifier. If I have 500 emails I want 500 rows in the dataframe, each row containing the entire contents of a single email. The problem is I can't seem to find a delimiter that doesn't somehow split the emails up. I think this is because the email header junk in the text files contain all sorts of exotic characters like <, (, :, etc... and of course the emails themselves are riddled with commas, periods and tabs.

I can read the emails into an array and the array will assign an entire email's contents to a single element, but when I make a dataframe out of this it will again split up the emails, so this doesn't work either.

How can I force pandas to write an entire files' contents to a single row even when that file contains tabs, whitespaces, commas, etc... ?

P.S. I need it to be a pandas dataframe because that works best with a machine learning application I am using.

Comment: Use a combination of characters as your delimiter like `'*;<|mydelim|>;*'`